# For a compact object $H$, is true that $H\simeq H_{\alpha_0}$ for some $\alpha_0$?

Tags: category-theory

Let $H$ be a compact object, i.e., the functor $[H,-]$ preserves filtered colimits.

Suppose $(H,\pi)=\text{colim}(H_{\alpha})$ with $(H_{\alpha})$ filtered. Then $(H\xrightarrow{\text{id}_H} H)=(H\xrightarrow{f}H_{\alpha_0}\xrightarrow{\pi_{\alpha_0}} H)$ for some $f$ and $\alpha_0$. Hence, $\pi_{\alpha_0}\circ f = \text{id}_H$.

I want to see $f \circ \pi_{\alpha_0} = \text{id}_{H_{\alpha_0}}$ but maybe this is not necessarily true.

Any help or counterexample?

Comment: It only follows that $f\circ\pi_{\alpha_0}$ is an idempotent, split by object $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you show is all that’s true: $H$ is a retract of some object in the diagram. Indeed if $e:H’\to H’$ is any idempotent which $H$ splits, then $H$ is the filtered colimit of a couple of different filtered diagrams made up of copies of $H’$, most obviously $H’\to H’\to\cdots$, where all the maps are $e$.